# Jackson Parsing for json object inside json

Tags: java, json, jackson, rest-assured, jackson-databind

I have sample json data like below

> {"data":{"detection":[{"category":"building","coordinates":{"xmin":"0.31","ymin":"0.42","ymax":"0.82","xmax":"0.89"},"accuracy":"0.66"}]}}

Trying to parse data field in jackson parser and created ObjectCategories class(setter getter) for its values.

```
@JsonProperty("categories")
private List<ObjectCategory> categories;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@JsonProperty(DATA)
private void unpackNested(Map<String,Object> data) {
    this.categories = (ArrayList<ObjectCategory>) data.get("detection");
}
```

If we execute the above code, getting this exception -  *getCategories().get(0).getAccuracy()* to *java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ObjectCategory*

*getCategories().get(0)* returns Map value. How to parse with my ObjectCategory class.

Comment: What's the declared type of `this.categories`?

Comment: Try `Map<String, List<ObjectCategory>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the value if you originally deserialized it to map.

```
this.categories = objectMapper
     .convertValue(data.get("detection"), 
                   new TypeReference<List<ObjectCategory>>() {});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This flow works fine. One more question, do we need pass objectMapper object to this class ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. Ideally, there shouldn't be a need to call `convert` if `data` was deserialized into a class that contains a `detection` field declared as `List<ObjectCategory>`. The suggested conversion makes sense if you needed to deserialize into map upstream.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Initially, *data* field was deserialized into a class but *data* is the only field available in that JSON. So, didn't want a separate class for that. Are you suggesting that is the good practice ?

Comment: @Tamilselvan I suppose that's up to you, but if I were you, I would keep your initial design as that makes Jackson bind once into a class instead of creating objects multiple times (first from json to maps, then from maps to custom class)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response.